# java email regex validation and prevent free space at the beginning and at the end

Tags: java, regex

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%\&'\*\+\-/\=\?\^_`\{\|\}~]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%\&'\*\+\-/\=\?\^_`\{\|\}~]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*
```

This is regex for validation email but it is not working as it should. I have tested many regex for now but all has problems.

Problem is that if you enter free space at the beginning and at the end email is alays valid.

like: `" test@gmail.com "`

how to prevent empty spaces?

Comment: and how does `trim()` not work

Comment: Valid email addresses are seen as invalid with your regex. [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/).

Comment: Trim is not regex. We need just regex...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a `^` in front of your regex and a `$` at the end, so it isn't allowed to start/end with a space anymore:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%\&'\*\+\-/\=\?\^_`\{\|\}~]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%\&'\*\+\-/\=\?\^_`\{\|\}~]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$
```

`^`and `$` denote the start and end of the input.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Comment: Why are you adding `(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})` at the end? You should have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses